# nohup import not process

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I tried to import job but my nohup command seems doesn't work.

```
devinim@koha-db57:~/kohaaktarim$ nohup mysql -u root -p kohadata < kohaaktarim.sql &
[1] 9619
devinim@koha-db57:~/kohaaktarim$ nohup: appending output to ‘nohup.out’


[1]+  Stopped                 nohup mysql -u root -p kohadata < kohaaktarim.sql
devinim@koha-db57:~/kohaaktarim$ jobs
[1]+  Stopped                 nohup mysql -u root -p kohadata < kohaaktarim.sql
devinim@koha-db57:~/kohaaktarim$ gf
gf: command not found
devinim@koha-db57:~/kohaaktarim$ fg
nohup mysql -u root -p kohadata < kohaaktarim.sql
Enter password:
```

I entered password but it's not responding. I open another terminal and connect there. I can't see any nohup when I search `ps -ef|grep nohup` . what should i do? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## ROOT CAUSE

The password option is not correct. When expressed like this

```
nohup mysql -u root -p kohadata < kohaaktarim.sql &
```

The word `kohadata` is being understood as the database

## SUGGESTION #1

Either remove the space after `-p`

```
nohup mysql -u root -pkohadata < kohaaktarim.sql &
```

or change the option to `--password=`

```
nohup mysql -u root --password=kohadata < kohaaktarim.sql &
```

## SUGGESTION #2

If the word `kohadata` is the database, you need to add the password

```
MYSQL_DB=kohadata
MYSQL_PASS=rootpassword
nohup mysql -u root -p${MYSQL_PASS} -D${MYSQL_DB} < kohaaktarim.sql &
```

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!